# JOIN tables from different dbs

Tags: mysql, join

I need to fix a query that used to join different tables residing in the same db. Now some of the tables were moved to a different db, while on the same server. Is there a way to modify the query to indicate where each table is?

Comment: Just add the database name as a prefix before the table name. `SELECT ... FROM db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2 ...`

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html for more information